# numpy import error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I got the following numpy error. I have tried 1. But it did solve the problem. Would you please let me know how to fix the problem? Thanks.

```
$ python3
Python 3.8.0a3 (v3.8.0a3:9a448855b5, Mar 25 2019, 17:05:20) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.8 from "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.1" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'
```

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/12977

Comment: What is the specific solution? I don't have conda. How to figure what is the package installation conflict?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I had Python 3.8.0a3 installed. I updated it to 3.8.1. Now the problem is solved.